# nodejs http server can not access to apache's virtualhost

Tags: node.js, apache, proxy

I use nodejs to set up a proxy on my macbook,and set my phone's wifi proxy to my macbook's ip,
It works,but I can not access to my virtualhost(which's seted on my macbook by apache) from my phone.
Here is the node js proxy.

```
;(function(){
    var webServer;
    function onWebServerCreate(request, response){
        var client,clientOption,clientRequest;
        clientOption = {
            host: request.headers['host'],
            post: 80,
            method: request.method,
            path: request.url,
            headers: request.headers
        }
        clientRequest = http.request(clientOption);

        clientRequest.addListener('response', function (clientResponse) {
            clientResponse.addListener('data', function(chunk) {
                response.write(chunk);
            });
            clientResponse.addListener('end', function() {
                response.end();
            });
            response.writeHead(clientResponse.statusCode, clientResponse.headers);
         });
        request.addListener('data', function(chunk) {
            clientRequest.write(chunk);
        });
        request.addListener('end', function() {
            clientRequest.end();
        });    
        request.on('error', function (err) {
        });        
    }

    webServer = http.createServer(onWebServerCreate)
    webServer.listen(8089);
)();
```

Here is my virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:8088>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/unbug/web/"
    ServerName ilabs.test.com
    ServerAdmin test@corp.netease.com    
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host2.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host2.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

I cant access to my virtualhost neither by "ilabs.test.com:8088" nor by "my macbook's IP:8088"
I cant change my virtualhost's setting.I have to make it work by nodeJS,how can I make my node proxy works?

I can see if I change my virtualhost's listener port to 80 will be ok,but the 80 post is for other server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Node.js proxy is hard coded to port 80. Your VirtualHost is on 8088.

You can do a quick test, change 80 to 8088 in your Node.js and see if it works.

Comment: I did changed the request post to 8088,it still can not access.Also this proxy not just for access my virtualhost,it must can access to any web site.